# Can't open SFML 2 window if not in same scope

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, sfml

I have built myself a little [entity based game framework](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/what-is-an-entity-framework) that does no rendering or window management by itself but provides structure. An equivalent to an MVC framework really.

I am now trying to put it into practice by rendering a simple window with SFML 2. I have done it in the past in this environment (my Ubuntu 12.04 box) with more stringy code, so I know my SFML 2 libraries are working correctly.

I am however getting a segmentation fault when trying to access my `sf::RenderWindow` instance. I have run it through GDB and everything is there, but when trying to execute a method (which GDB *can* see), it dies.

This only happens though if I try to access my window like this.

```
class BasicGame : public arc::Game
{
public:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
};

class BasicGameSystem : public arc::System
{
protected:
    BasicGame* game;
};

class RenderSystem : public BasicGameSystem
{
public:
    void start()
    {
        game->window.create(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Basic arc example");
        game->window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    }
};
```

The pointer, `game`, is not null. I can dereference it in GDB and it will return an instance of `BasicGame`. `game->window` also exists, and GDB can see `game->window.create`, it will even moan at me for not supplying any arguments if I try to execute it.

If I try to execute `setFramerateLimit` manually with GDB using a breakpoint it will also segfault.

If I change my start method to this though...

```
void start()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Basic arc example");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
}
```

It works absolutely fine. Well, the window closes instantly, but no segfault.

Does `sf::RenderWindow` need to be in the same scope? Does it's default constructor break it?

I am still pretty new to C++, so I may be doing something utterly stupid, but any help on this would be much appreciated. I have been searching and tinkering for hours but I just can't work it out. Hopefully this is enough information too.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Just for a little more information. I am compiling with `clang++` although I have tried `g++` too with the same result. And here is the backtrace from GDB.

```
#0  0xb7cd0981 in sf::Window::close() () from /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so.2
#1  0xb7cd131e in sf::Window::create(sf::VideoMode, std::string const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so.2
#2  0x080496a3 in RenderSystem::start (this=0xbffff0f0) at examples/basic.cpp:26
#3  0x0804b60e in arc::SystemList::add (this=0xbffff128, system=0xbffff0f0) at src/SystemList.cpp:17
#4  0x08049f79 in arc::Game::addSystem (this=0xbffff128, system=0xbffff0f0) at src/Game.cpp:11
#5  0x08048cfc in main () at examples/basic.cpp:73
```

I have no idea why close is being run... I have one occurrence in my codebase which is listening for the window close event. Taking it out makes no difference. Just thought I would make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The pointer, game, is not null. I can dereference it in GDB and it will return an instance of BasicGame.

The key point is to have a **valid** instance of `BasicGame`. From the code snippet you gave, it looks like you didn't use `new` so your pointer is pointing to a non-allocated memory region.

Consider the following code :

```
int* x = new int;
*x = 58;
delete x;
std::cout << x << " points to the value " << *x << std::endl; // unpredictable behaviour!
```

After deleting `x` you still can print its old address but if you try to access its content you might (but not necessarily) crash your program.

To prevent such mistake your should always add `x = 0;` (or `x = nullptr;` in C++11) and initialise your attributs :

```
BasicGameSystem() : game(0) { }
```

This way, you **will** know when you access invalid memory region because your program will crash.

Comment: Game is set to NULL elsewhere in the program using the `System` constructor. It is then assigned to an instance using another method later on but before I try to access it and it segfaults.

Comment: In my main method I declare my game instance and add systems to it. The systems have their game value set when added.

Comment: Sorry for all these comments... but your answer made me check my assignment code and it turns out the NULL assignment was being lost when I extended the class. The constructor was setting it on the wrong value. So my game value is not being set! I think you are right. I will mark as correct if this really is the problem.

Comment: I have followed my code through. The pointer should be assigned yet it's still null from my constructor. It's almost as if I have two threads running but I have written nothing of the sort. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you followed your code ? with a debugger ? You can check that you are not shadowing an attribute with some other variable.

Comment: I set a breakpoint early on in my program and then stepped through it. Luckily it is very simple so it is pretty easy to walk the whole thing. I saw it set the game pointer to null/0 in my constructor and then assigned to a `Game` class instance. Only it doesn't seem to assign. It executes the line and the values seem okay but in the next steps it's back to null. My only use of null in the whole program is that constructor.

Comment: I think I have worked it out. I am overloading my `game` pointer. The lower one is set but the upper one in the child class is still NULL. So I need a way to override a classes property correctly so that inherited methods will affect the overridden value and not the original in the base class.

Comment: You were right in a way. I could not fix it so I stripped everything down and made it simpler. It works now, just a bit plain. Thanks for your help.